# Drawing a path with MKMapView problems

Tags: swift, nsmutableset

I'm trying to draw a path (with `MKMapView`). But I have:

> NSInvalidArgumentException ', reason:' *** - [NSMutableOrderedSet addObject:]: object can not be nil '.

I have this button action with a `NSTimer` that calls the function `stop`

```
@IBAction func startRoute(sender: UIButton) {
    // Timer stop() function
    // Each 4 seconds
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.stop), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

And this is my `stop()` function, which puts a "Start Point" and it is going adding the current location to the vector called `points` of type `var points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []` and draw the path with the addOverlay.

```
func stop() {
    if (self.initialFlag == 0) {
        // Put flag to 1
        self.initialFlag = 1

        // Add a Annotation
        let sourceAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        sourceAnnotation.title = "Start Point"
        sourceAnnotation.coordinate = (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate)!
        self.mapView.showAnnotations([sourceAnnotation], animated: true)                        
    }

    // Get current point location
    let currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!,(self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!);

    // We add points every 4 seconds then draw the map points
    self.points.append(currentLocation)


    // Draw the path

    geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &points[0], count: points.count)

    // And I have the error in this line below.
    self.mapView.addOverlay(self.geodesic, level: .AboveRoads)

}
```

Comment: Try to get rid of force unwrapping optionals and use guard or if let syntax to unwrap it. Then check if locationManager.location.coordinate is available at the moment you call it. If it doesn't fix the problem, post updated code in the question.

Comment: use the debugger to find out where it crashes. maybe points isn't valid and MKGeodesicPolyline isnt valid then and MKGeodesicPolyline.points is nil?

Comment: what is points[0] and whats geodesic.points and whats geodesic.pointCount

Answer (score 0):

Hey it looks like if you don't have enought coordinates to create MKGeodesicPolyline it throws an error, My solution was it

```
if points.count > 1{
   geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &points[0], count: points.count)
   self.mapView.addOverlay(self.geodesic, level: .AboveRoads)
}
```